# django model field check instance

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a models like

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now I am querying this like

```
m = MyModel.objets.get(id=2)
```

Here I want to check if the field is of certain type I want to do some stuff like

```
from django.db.models import DateTimeField

if isinstance(m.updated_on, DateTimeField):
    // do something
```

But here I am getting false. 
Is there any workaround by which I can achieve this ??

Comment: Meta Classes... Very confusing. :-) After instantiation, `updated_on` is not a `DateTimeField`.  it is a `datetime.datetime`. see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateTimeField

Comment: You can query the class of the object, but that does not make sense since the type will not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the type of field: 
`Model._meta.get_field("fieldname")`

You can use this:

`from django.db.models import DateTimeField
if isinstance(MyModel._meta.get_field('updated_on'),DateTimeField):
     ...`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the data in the field would be anything other than what you have defined it as.

But your problem is that the type of the *field* is not the same as the type of the *data*, and it's the latter you care about. The type of data in a DateTimeField is `datetime.datetime`.

So:

```
from datetime import datetime
if isinstance(m.updated_on, datetime):
    ...
```

Comment: The OP probably wants to write a generic mechanism using introspection.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just dont want to check for `datetime`. Lets say its `FileField`. If it is instance of file field I want to return url of the field.